# How to fix seemingly missing packages in Ubuntu Software / GNOME Software?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, 22.04, gnome-software

On Ubuntu 22.04, when trying to remove software from Ubuntu Software Center or GNOME Software I get in almost any cases an error saying "no packages to remove". Removing those packages using apt does work however, and when going to the details page in the store apps, I can start the app normally.

Specifically it seems this is the case for all software that was installed as part of the initial installation. Packages installed later can be removed. For the affected packages, GNOME Software does also not show the app icon (Ubuntu Software Center does). See also the attached screenshot (code was installed later and can be successfully removed from either store app).

Somehow this feels like a cache issue, but reinstalling gnome-software did not help.

Can I force GNOME Software / Ubuntu Software to "reindex" or reload the installed packages?

In case this is relevant:

- this problem manifested directly after a fresh install of 22.04. With 20.04. before I had no such problems
- this is a tuxedo computers laptop and installation was done using their WebFAI stick/tool

[image: Screenshot of GNOME Software showing missing packages]